# Voyager: upload data and images location

Tags: laravel-5, voyager

I just prepared this nice shopping website code

https://github.com/drehimself/laravel-ecommerce-example

I go admin page then upload some new items but 
those item data and images are not dislayed.

I tryed to look contoller page but I couldn't find where are at.
Here is the web.php file

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});
```

Could somebody teach me where should I change?

Comment: most probably you are missing sym link
Laravel voyager works on symbolic  links structure 

try php artisan storage:link

Comment: @Saad Bhutto Thank you for answering me. I did php artisan storage:link
So I got this message The "public/storage" directory already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view all routes from

```
vendor\TCG\Voyager\routes\voyager.php
```

If you want to override any route then update in `web.php`

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Saurabh Dhariwal. I've been wating answer I appreciate a lot. I look the file ...but unfortunately as my programing skill couldn't solve my problem where should I fix or correct etc... Anyway Thank you so much!